# Wronskian-Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

The equations below are matrices:

Consider the vectors $y^{(1)}  (t)$=$\begin{pmatrix}t \\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and
 $y^{(2)}$  (t)=$\begin{pmatrix}t^2 \\2t \end{pmatrix}$
    (a) Compute the Wronskian of $y^{(1)}$ and $ y^{(2)}$.
I have computed the wronskian and it came up to be $t^2$

(b)In what intervals are $y^{(1)}$  and $y^{(2)}$ linearly independent?
Since the wronskian is not equal to 0, therefore it is linearly independent in any interval because any interval contains at least a non zero t-value

This is all I have done!!

And I am confused about the parts (c) and (d)
The questions are;

(c ) What conclusions can be drawn about the coefficients in the system of homogeneous differential equations satisfied by $y^{(1)}$ and $y^{(2)}~$??

( d) Find the system of equations and verify the conclusion of part (c )

Can anybody help  me???

Comment: Your formatting seems to have gotten corrupted. Can you please update your question? Regards

Comment: @user91745 the formatting is still broken. Let me show you: http://puu.sh/4jhGy.png

Comment: I think the question is clear now and needs to be opened again.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: If you dont mind opening the question now as it has been edited.

Comment: Are you sure that the Wronskian is $t^2$? Shouldn't it be $2t-t^3$?

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro: supposed to be $t^2$, question is edited again.

Answer (score 1):

Part b: $-\infty\ to +\infty$

part c: Not supposed be continuous at t= 0.

part d: you may want to use:

```
                                      2
            | 1  2t | = | a  b | | t t  |
            | 0  2  |   | c  d | | 1 2t |
```

Comment: I agree with you on this.

Comment: THink about part d and work on your own.